# Zend_Db_Exception - how to get adapter

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

In my project on PHP with Zend Framework i have many mysql servers and many pdo_mysql adapters.
In one moment i'm catching exception (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception).
How i can to determinate which adapter throws this exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in Zend_Exceptions classes to get the origin of the Exception, but the the `getTrace()` method. You can use this **getTrace** to get the Zend_Db_Select object object, and if your version of Zend Framework is not too old you have the getAdapter class on it (if you do not have the getAdapter on Zend_Db_Select it's not a very hard to code method, as $this->_adapter is present). So here is a code which can be used on the catch section to get details on the adapter configuration:

```
} catch (Exception $e) {
    foreach($e->getTrace() as $trace) {
        if($trace['class']=='Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract' || 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract'==$trace['class']) {
            $zendDbSelect = $trace['args'][0];
            $zendDbAdapter = $zendDbSelect->getAdapter();
            $conn = $zendDbAdapter->getConfig();
            //output adapter configuration, more useful things could be done
            // with that if you want
            Zend_Debug::dump($conn);
            // stop the loop on traces
            break;
        }
    }
    // to something else with the exception if you want
}
```